# Edit all files in directory tree with regular expression on Windows

Tags: regex, windows, perl

I am looking for a program that can edit all files in directory tree like Perl on Unix systems. The files are xml's and another folders.

The regex should delete all the content placed in `<loot></loot>` brackets.

for example file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<monster name="Dragon"/>
<health="10000"/>
<immunities>
    <immunity fire="1"/>
</immunities>
<loot>
<item id="1"/>
<item id="3"/>
    <inside>
        <item id="6"/>
    </inside>
</item>
</loot>
```

the file should look after edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<monster name="Dragon"/>
<health="10000"/>
<immunities>
    <immunity fire="1"/>
</immunities>
<loot>
</loot>
```

Comment: You can install perl for windows. Or use a copy of sed for windows. Or a VBscript

Comment: There is no problem with running Perl on Windows.  It installs in minutes. You can make use of [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), or better yet [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm), to apply processing to all files. For individual file processing use a module for `XML`, either [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm).

Answer (score 1):

I would shy away from anything regex based - XML simply doesn't work with regular expressions.

But fortunately, Perl for Windows is readily available. And better yet, if you go with Strawberry perl, it comes bundled with both `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`.

At which point the problem becomes inanely simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;
use XML::Twig;

sub delete_loot {
   my ( $twig, $loot ) = @_;
   foreach my $loot_entry ( $loot -> children ) {
      $loot_entry -> delete;
   }
   $twig -> flush;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented', 
                              twig_handlers => { 'loot' => \&delete_loot ,
          '_all_' => sub { $_ - > flush } } ); 

foreach my $file ( File::Find::Rule  -> file()
                                     -> name ( '*.xml.txt' )
                                     -> in ( 'C:\tmp' ) ) {

    print "Processing $file\n";
    $twig -> parsefile_inplace($file); 
}
```

Of course, this *also* assumes that your XML is, in fact, XML - which your example isn't. If that example is actually correct, then you should really hit whoever wrote it around the head with a rolled up copy of the XML Spec whilst chanting 'don't make fake XML'.

Comment: I put the correct path `-> in ( 'C:\Users\PIO\Documents\serv\data\monsters' ) )` , and changed the  `-> name ( '*.xml.txt' )` into `-> name ( '*.xml' )` because `*.xml.txt` had no effect (every files in folders are .xml's). It has processed all files, but only the first file is edited correctly, and the rest has been cleaned (empty files).

Comment: Hmm, can't check it right now, but maybe an _all_ handler to flush. Edited accordingly.

Comment: On line `$twig -> parsefile_inplace($file);` shows error **Can't call method "flush_up_to" on an undefinied value at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 8452**.  The effect after executing program is copying first file, giving it strange name (hJ1DKyO1tH), that contains the same code, but on <loot> bracelets put some enters(newlines). I haven't found any solution to this error, and the Strawberry has been installed correctly (I think).  I have installed the latest recommended strawberry for Windows 64bit. Twig.pm on 8454 line has this code `$elt->twig->flush_up_to( $up_to, @_);`